# Посоветуйте научно-популярные книги по computer science

Tags: алгоритм, книги

Разумеется, вы знаете книги, которые простым языком объясняют, как всё устроено в определённой области науки, разбирают интересные примеры и вкратце суммируют, почему она нужна и полезна. Про разные разделы физики и математики таких книг полным полно. Однако, я с удивлением не нагуглил ничего интересного на тему компьютеров и алгоритмов. Конечно, есть "Энциклопедия профессора Фортрана" и "Я был в компьютерном городе", но они совсем для младших классов да и устарели.

Быть может, кто-нибудь подскажет книги такого толка? Интересуют как книги, которые можно дать почитать школьнику для подстёгивания интереса к предмету, так и томики для уже более-менее сформировавшихся специалистов.

**UPD** Спрашиваю именно про научно-*популярные* издания, а не учебники. Как, например "Гёдель, Эшер, Бах" Хофстедера или "Занимательная физика" Перельмана

Comment: Кнута уже читали?

Comment: Structure & implementation of computer programs. Не кратко, непростым языком, на лишпе, зато с подробным разбором критически важных повседневныз моментов.

Comment: > Кнута уже читали?
Да, читал. Ну очень научно-популярный. И для школьников, ага.

>Structure & implementation of computer programs.
Это всё же учебник

Comment: Может "Ради удовольствия" (Just for Fun) Линуса и "Хакеры: Герои компьютерной революции" (Hackers: heroes of computer revolution)  Стивена Леви это именно то что надо для пробуждения интереса?

Хотя, я конечно не могу быть уверенным, что все эти истории затронут человека, пока еще не знакомого с IT.

Comment: "Код" Чарльза Петцольда

Comment: Научпопа в информационных технлогиях быть не может. ИТ это инженерное приложения многих наук, поэтому о научпопе говорить не приходится. Есть книги попроще, есть посложнее, но ни одна из них научпопом не является. Наиболее простая и интересная книга, на мой взгляд, это "Код" Петцольда. Вообще, Петцольд это, по моему мнению, лучший автор в мире ИТ.

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем уж научпоп, но возможно понравится, написана хорошо.

[Код. Тайный язык информатики](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/125884/)

Answer (score 1):

[Альфред Реньи. "Записки студента по теории информации"](http://www.alleng.ru/d/math/math190.htm)

Answer (score 1):

- [Дж. Маккормик. Девять алгоритмов, которые изменили будущее](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/27549878/)
- [Дж. Глик. Информация. История. Теория. Поток](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/24807519/)

Answer (score 1):

http://computersbooks.net/
неплохой сайт с кучей инфы по сабжу!